# How do I exclude a folder from ASP.NET Core's static files?

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a folder under `"wwwroot"` that I don't want to include when returning static files.

I want to return various directories under `"wwwroot"` (for instance `"wwwroot/images"`) and this middleware step enables that:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I can pass this `StaticFileOptions` to configure what's returned.

I want to exclude a directory (for instance `"wwwroot/node_modules"`) and not allow any statif files to be served from that.

There doesn't appear to be a filter I can use on `StaticFileOptions` - how should I apply that filter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't look for an option on the static files middleware - instead *any* middleware can be filtered using `MapWhen` or `UseWhen`. This allows you to only register the middleware for routes where a condition is passed.

For instance, to exclude `"wwwroot/node_modules"`:

```
app.UseWhen(
    context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/node_modules"),
    appBuilder => appBuilder.UseStaticFiles());
```

This will now only apply the static files middleware when the route doesn't start with `"/node_modules"`.

- `UseWhen` falls through to the next middleware if it fails
- `MapWhen` only goes on to the next middleware if the context filter applies